# Where can I find a bundled version of SAPUI5 resource files for local dev?

Tags: sapui5, ui5-tooling

**TL;DR;**
Where can I find a bundled SAPUI5 runtime/SDK for local development?

---

**Long story:** The project generated by `easy-ui5` loads the UI5 framework from the relative URL (resources/...) which with "modern" UI5 tooling, will be dynamically generated. However, the DX is not ideal. It's pretty sluggish.

The following screenshots were taken from the exact `hello-world` app generated by `easy-ui5`'s `ts-app` config.

*With CDN https://ui5.sap.com:*

[image: With CDN https://ui5.sap.com]

*With Downloaded resource folder from https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/#sapui5:*

[image: With Downloaded resource folder from https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/#sapui5 - Browser Cache Disabled]

*Dynamically Generated by UI5 Tooling - Browser Cache Enabled*

[image: Dynamically Generated by UI5 Tooling - Cache On]

All the above screenshots capture only JS downloads. Downloading 300+ JS files or even *just* 36 for local development in 2022 is quite hard to swallow. Does the UI5 team have any plan to publish the controls/libraries/SDK (bundled ofc) on NPM for developers to consume locally? Besides the performance issue, I don't want to rely on Internet connection for local development.

Comment: You could create an issue at https://github.com/SAP/ui5-tooling/issues and ask about the performance issue in UI5 Tooling

Comment: Thanks, will do that.

Comment: For other readers, here is the created GH issue by Xucong: https://github.com/SAP/ui5-tooling/issues/647. Consider giving a  and subscribing to that issue if you're interested